# Find the norm of the operator $T:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ defined by $Tx := (x_1, x_1+x_2, x_3, x_3+x_4, x_5, x_5+x_6, \ldots)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $T : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ (involving complex numbers) be defined by
$$
Tx := (x_1, x_1+x_2, x_3, x_3+x_4, x_5, x_5+x_6, \ldots).
$$
What is $\|T\|$?

Essentially I've tried :

1. To find $M \geq 0$ s.t. $\|Tx\| \leq M \|x\|$ and $\|T\| \geq M$. Cauchy-Schwarz led me nowhere. The triangle inequality gives $\|Tx\| \leq 2 \|x\|$, but I've not been able to show that $\|T\| \geq 2$ (in fact I don't think $2$ is small enough).
2. To maximise
   $$
   \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}
   $$
   for $x \neq 0$, or equivalently
   $$
   \|Tx\|
   $$
   for $\|x\|=1$. I didn't succeed.
3. I've tried to write $|x_k| = x_k e^{- i\theta_k}$ and see if I could simplify some things or recognize known expressions. I failed with this idea.

Apparently there is a way to use matrices, but I don't see how.

Comment: Okay, write $\ell^2 = E \oplus F$, where the direct sum is orthogonal, and $E$ is the subspace where all components with even index are $0$, $F$ the subspace where the components with odd index are $0$. Then $T$ becomes $(e,f) \mapsto (e,e+f)$ if we identify each of $E$ and $F$ with $\ell^2$. Obviously(?) for $\lVert e\rVert$ and $\lVert f\rVert$ fixed, the norm of $T(e,f)$ is maximised when $\lVert e+f\rVert = \lVert e\rVert + \lVert f\rVert$. _Now_ it is not too hard to get $\lVert T\rVert$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably know that the norm of a diagonal matrix is the supremum of absolute values of its diagonal entries. Here's a generalization of this:

#### Claim

Suppose $T:\ell^2\to\ell^2$ has invariant subspaces $\{V_k:k=1,2\dots\}$ which are mutually orthogonal and satisfy $\ell^2=\bigoplus_k V_k$. Let $T_k:V_k\to V_k$ be the induced operator on $V_k$, essentially the restriction of $T$ to this subspace. Then
$$\|T\|=\sup_k \|T_k\|$$

#### Proof

It's easy to see that $\|T\|\ge   \|T_k\|$ for all $k$. Conversely, given any vector $x\in \ell_2$ we can write it as $x=\sum_k x_k$ with $x_k\in V_k$. Then
$$
\|Tx\|^2 = \sum_k \|T_k x_k\|^2 \le \sup_k \|T_k\|^2 \sum_k \| x_k\|^2 = \sup_k \|T_k\|^2 \|x\|^2
$$
which proves $\|T\|\le \sup_k \|T_k\|$. $\quad\Box$

Armed with the above (which is useful not only on this occasion), you can find $\|T\|$ just by examining the operator norm of $2\times 2$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Nice. So I think $\|T\| = \left( \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: [WolframAlpha agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=norm+%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%5D%5D)